Struggle to bootstrap MicroCloud
I’m kinda new to this whole world…
I’m trying to setup MicroCloud inside of LXD environment on an ubuntu 22.04 desktop ryzen 3900x with 64G ram, virtualizing 5 vms running the 4 snaps, each has 8G ram and 4 cpu, I have configure the network exactly as stated in documentation:
https://canonical-microcloud.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/microcloud/tutorial/get_started/ 1
also this video:
https://ubuntu.com/engage/introduction-to-microcloud 1
microcloud init always stops/halts at searching for the nodes and never finds any of them
I have two networks one is the default lxdbr0 netwrok configured and connected to all 5 vms, a bridge network default made by lxd init. and the microbr0 created with the tutorial, I haven’t passed accessing the first network even to think about the second.
the vms are pingable and I even tried to install microk8s on them and the nodes were successfully connected.
I tried different versions of lxd on the host machine currently using 5.21.2-22f93f4
I tried different version of all the snaps, mixed and matched, with no hope.
would be please help help me by guiding me through which logs shall I look into?
Thanks in advance !

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].

I was challenged with this myself infact I was pretty annoyed they advertised a 5 step installation process that just doesnt work ... then I thought to myself I have some old DEllT7500 192GB Memory with some old SAS disks and its doesnt work what would the difference between those kind people who published the docs and me the anser was simple I installed KVM setup three nodes running jammy and behold it worked ... in otherwords they are using vitual environments on the laptops to write this stuff not real servers with real problems
